# AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'shh'

Tags: web3.py

- Web3.py version: 4.2.1
- Python: 3.5.2
- OS: linux
- geth version: `1.8.0-unstable`
- I am running `geth` with `--shh` flag and `--rpcapi "admin,eth,net,web3,debug,shh"`

---

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))          

print ("web3 =", web3.version.api) #4.2.1
print(web3.shh) #error occurs
```

When I try to run following code above, I am having following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dd.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(web3.shh)
AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'shh'
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For `web3.py==5.x.x`**

[GethShh](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html?highlight=shh#gethshh)

> The `web3.geth.shh` object exposes methods to interact with the RPC APIs
>   under the `shh_` namespace.

---

**For `web3.py==4.x.x`**

=> We have to add the following line of code in order to fix the error for the `web3.py`:

```
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")
```

=> We also have to add the following line for web3.js. Than use `shh`.

```
var Shh = require('web3-shh');   
var shh = new Shh(Shh.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:8545');
```

---

**Please see following solution for `web3.py`:**

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

from web3.shh import Shh  # Added line
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")   # Added line

# Now we call web3.shh as we would like:

# Example
print(web3.shh.version) #5.0
kId = web3.shh.newKeyPair();    
print(kId)
print(web3.shh.getPrivateKey(kId))
...
```

**Please see following solution for `web3.js`:**

```
$ npm install web3-shh
```

Example code:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));    
if(!web3.isConnected()){console.log("notconnected"); process.exit();}

var Shh = require('web3-shh');
// "Shh.providers.givenProvider" will be set if in an Ethereum supported browser.
var shh = new Shh(Shh.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:8545');

var kId = shh.newSymKey().then(console.log); //returns a valid value.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.parity.html#parityshh):

> The Whisper protocol is in flux, with incompatible versions supported
>   by different major clients.

So it is not currently included by default in the web3 instance.

Comment: What, you don't like this answer??? `shh` is not currently included by default in the web3 instance. What more do you want???

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a solution for how to opt-in would have made the answer more complete.

Comment: the docs link is dead

Comment: @alper: Yeah, they keep breaking them (and so do the guys at web3.js). Anyway, [here is the new one](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.parity.html#parityshh).